# How to add variable to docker daemon in CentOS?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I want to create registry mirror in docker. I read this [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/articles/registry_mirror/). So,I want to add this variable "--registry-mirror=http://10.0.0.2:5000" to docker daemon when it start.

I have succeeded in mac. I add the line to /var/lib/boot2docker/profile:

```
EXTRA_ARGS="--registry-mirror=http://192.168.59.103:5555"
```

It can work after adding in mac. So I do the same thing in CentOS. I use the command in this [question:I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472068/what-is-the-difference-b-w-service-docker-start-and-docker-d):

```
sudo sed -i 's|other_args=|other_args=--registry-mirror=http://<my-docker-mirror-host> |g' /etc/sysconfig/docker
sudo sed -i "s|OPTIONS='|OPTIONS='--registry-mirror=http://<my-docker-mirror-host> |g" /etc/sysconfig/docker
sudo service docker restart
```

and it makes my "/etc/sysconfig/docker" like below in CentOS, and this is my docker file:

```
# /etc/sysconfig/docker
#
# Other arguments to pass to the docker daemon process
# These will be parsed by the sysv initscript and appended
# to the arguments list passed to docker -d

OPTIONS=--selinux-enabled -H fd:// -g="/opt/apps/docker"

other_args="--registry-mirror=http://10.11.150.76:5555"
```

Then, I restart docker using this command:

```
service docker restart
```

But, the mirror didn't work in CentOS. I use command:

```
ps -ef
```

It did't add the variable to docker daemon. what is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference b/w "service docker start" and "docker -d"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472068/what-is-the-difference-b-w-service-docker-start-and-docker-d)

Comment: @booyaa No, I use the command on centos, it didn't work.

Comment: so why not update the original post with the correct information rather than open a similar looking post?

Comment: In original post, I just want to know the different b/w they.

Comment: Why not put everything into `OPTIONS`? `other_args` doesn't mean anything to docker.

Comment: @superbob How to add it? Is it ok to just add to OPTIONS? Can you edit my docker file and answer this question?

Comment: @v11, I don't see a Dockerfile in your question, only the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/docker` config file which is not a Dockerfile

Comment: I've summed up everything to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file, change:

```
OPTIONS=--selinux-enabled -H fd:// -g="/opt/apps/docker"
```

into:

```
OPTIONS=--selinux-enabled -H fd:// -g="/opt/apps/docker" --registry-mirror=http://10.11.150.76:5555
```

I can't help you with `other_args`, I don't know this option.

Comment: Thanks, It is ok to add variable to docker daemon. But the mirror still can't run normally. I will accept your answer, and new a problem to ask why mirror can't run normally.

Comment: FYI, docker packaging differs from on distro to the other, on openSUSE with docker 1.6.2 which i'm using, `other_args` doesn't exist, moreover the parameter used in the sysconfig file is `DOCKER_OPTS` instead of the centos `OPTIONS`. That can be confusing.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea for that question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517388/how-to-create-docker-registry-mirror-on-centos?

Answer (score 0):

If you using `yum install docker`, you may get a problem with the docker service config file.

Then you need to check your system service config file, see if it using `other_args` as a parameter to start docker. By default, the service config file should placed at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`, edit it with any editor, check `ExecStart` part, add `other_args` to it.

For example, `ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d --selinux-enabled $other_args`

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea for that question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517388/how-to-create-docker-registry-mirror-on-centos?